# What is the size (in bytes) of an SSH login request?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

What is the size (in bytes) of an SSH login request?

In fact I just want to know what is the size of the login SSH request when it is send from the client to the SSH server. 
For a bandwidth point of view. 
If it is a regular user/password login.

Comment: wouldnt that would depend on the login method initiated by the client (interactive, public key, etc..)?

Comment: 12.....just kidding.  What are you asking?  Are you asking if a SSH login request is longer than non-SSH?

Comment: Download Wireshare 'http://www.wireshark.org/' and take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting under 6k for a complete login conversation. to a OpenSSH Debian server using PuTTY as a client and D-H key exchange. Hope that helps!